# App.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working through the University of Helsinki Full Stack Open course and I'm tearing my hear out with an error I just can't crack. I'm building a React web app that fetches data from the Rest Countries API (https://github.com/apilayer/restcountries). I'm trying to fetch a specific country (e.g. https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/aus) and render the name, capital, population, list of languages and flag. Everything except the list of languages works perfectly with this code:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios'

    const App = () => {
      const [ country, setCountry] = useState([])

   useEffect(() => {
        console.log('effect')
        axios
          .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/aus')
          .then(response => {
            console.log('promise fulfilled')
            setCountry(response.data)
          })
      }, [])
      console.log({country})

      return (
        <div>
            <h1>{country.name}</h1>
            <p>Capital: {country.capital}</p>
            <p>Population: {country.population}</p>
            <h2>Languages</h2>
            <h2>Flag</h2>
            <img
              src={country.flag}
              style={{width:200, height:128}}
            />
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

However, when I add the following to the ..., to try and render the list of languages, I get the error: "App.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

```
        <ul>
          {country.languages.map(language =>
            <li key={language.name}>{language.name}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
```

If anyone has any tips, it would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: If `country.languages` is set by the axios response, you won't be able to access it until the response is received by the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It errors on the first render when country is still equal to []. So on the first render it tries to call te `map` method on [].languages which is undefined and doesn't have the map method.

You can solve this by adding a check if country.languages is set, as such:

```
<ul>
  {country.languages && country.languages.map(language =>
    <li key={language.name}>{language.name}</li>
  )}
</ul>
```

The `map` method will now only get fired when country.languages is set.

Comment: This works and makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: No problem, if you click the checkmark on the top-left of my answer your question will be market as "solved"

Answer (score 0):

You can use ?. operator to avoid multiple && checks. Your code will be country?.languages?.map

Comment: Thanks gautamits. That's a nice shortcut.

Comment: Welcome @LidderDj, Happy to help. Please mark the question solved if soltions solved your problem.